# "esti" with just a subject

Tags: word-usage

Jen la frazo sekvanta.

> Estas Mario!

Normally, this would simply mean "It's Mario/Maria!" (name does not matter). However, what if one says it like this?

> Mario estas!

To my understanding, this could be read in one of two and a half ways.

- "Mario is!"

  - The intransitive "to be" here is used like in the famous saying "I think, therefore I am". That is to say, Mario "exists". I have enclosed the word in quotation marks, as I do not really mean "exists", or else I would have said "Mario ekzistas!". I simply mean that Mario is.
- "It's Mario!"

  - In this case, it is just a strange reordering of "Estas Mario!", and is perhaps just a weird alternate way of saying that. Then again, Mario *is* the subject here, either way, no? Or maybe it's to emphasize, ke Mario *estas*, kaj ne faras ion alian (ekzemple, malesti).
- "Mario is present/here!"

  - Speaking of "malesti", that brings up an interesting point. If "malesti" is "to not be [present]", "Mario estas!" would simply mean that Mario *is* present.

Ĉu tio senchavas?

**Premia Demando**

Parolante pri la frazo "I think, therefore I am"...

> Ĉu eblas, ke oni ekzistas, sed ne estas?
>   Tio estas, ĉu oni, kiu ne pensas, sed ekzistas, ne estas?
>   Ekzemple, "Estas la <kio ajn>, kiu ne pensas! Ĝi do ne estas."
>   Ĉu estas io, kiu ne estas???

Comment: Similar to _It's raining._ = _Pluvas._ (Hajlas, Neĝas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Estas Mario!
> ```
>
> Normally, this would simply mean "It's Mario/Maria!"

Mmm, not really. If there is no context, it's not clear what you mean. On its own it *feels* like an incomplete sentence waiting for additional information:

```
Estas Mario ... la venonta prezidento!
Estas Mario ... ĉeporde, bonvolu malfermi!
```

If you want to say something like "It's Mario!" in the sense *present/here* you would use [jen](http://vortaro.net/#jen):

```
Jen Mario!
```

If the context is clear, you could do without *tiu* and be understood. For example, en *Gerda Malaperis*:

```
Post duonhoro, iu envenis. Estis Bob!
```

In that case Bob is the one that just arrived. But, if the previous sentence was unrelated, or if Bob could belong to different parts of it, then it's not easy to figure out what *Estis Bob!* means:

```
Ĉiuj ploretis. Estis Bob!

La ulo mortigis sian najbaron. Estis Bob!
```

What I'm trying to say is that in order to be sure you get the meaning across, you have to either use *jen*, *tiu* or provide a clear context (that actually takes the place of *tiu*).

About *malest/*, it means *mank/*, not *neest/*.

About *mi pensas, do mi estas*, the [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito%2C_ergo_sum#Interpretation) is not clear and neither is the way [to correctly translate it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito%2C_ergo_sum#Translation). So I think it belongs in another question.